# CSS: how to keep image never modified with same "offset" all the time?

Tags: html, css, image

```
<img src="/static/img/footer-top.png" 
     style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; position: relative; left: 0">

<footer id="footer" style="background-color: #214269; height: 100%">
    <div class="footerrow">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="footer-box">
                    <ul class="footer-links">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/fr/legal/a-propos/">À propos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/fr/legal/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                        <!-- blabla -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

That's what you get:

[image]

The problem is when you resize the window, the image is resized too, this makes 2 bad things :

- the logo is not properly aligned anymore
- the whole logo is smaller or taller

Like this:

[image: mis-aligned logo]

I didnt find the solution on google: image not resized, with fixed offset **and** not a `background-image`, *but a tag* **`img`**.

Comment: dont use `width:100%` in img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your images up with their actual values in the HTML, like so:

```
<img class="vanish" src="images/colours.png" alt="Colourful painting" width="480" height="615">
```

In the above example, the actual size of the image I'm linking to is 480 by 615.

Then control the positioning and re-size if you need to via your CSS file.

**Remember:** *it's okay to make your image smaller via CSS, but if you're not using the original larger size image then make sure to replace it with the largest you actually intend to use.*

So, for example: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg6owbtn/2/)

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.image-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  word-spacing: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sUB6EMh.png" width="200" height="200">
    <p>HOME ABOUT GALLERY CONTACT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I'll never get CSS properly I think.... I've updated your code to my needs: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg6owbtn/3/

Comment: You'll get it! I'm still learning myself, most of the time I feel like I'm fumbling around hacking at the code until something fits. As I hack away, the code gets more efficient. Don't worry about making a mess.

Here's another quick example if you wanted to keep the image directly above the HOME menu button without using position properties: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg6owbtn/4/